# MongoDB mass update is not working

Tags: mongodb-query

I'm trying to sanitize a set of data by overwriting all the email values in a table (via [mongodb reference here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)). The following doesn't cause errors but also does not update any values:

```
db.applicants.update(
    { institution_id: { $gt: 1 } }, 
    {$set: {email: "sanitizedmail@there.com"}},
    { multi: true })
```

and sample record:

```
{
    "id": "0003ee8c-2288-11e4-9610-0015c5f288ee",
    "created_at": "8/12/14 9:24",
    "updated_at": "8/12/14 9:25",
    "email": "some@there.com",
    "institution_id": "379",
}
```

Comment: could you show us example document structure?

Comment: @profesor79 Thanks. Added an example here:  https://gist.github.com/imarichardson/60a8a3516c09343afe44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your data structure the

> institution_id

field is type: text (2), so **$gt** will be not able to act.

Change it  to integer using snippet provided below:

```
db.applicants.find( { 'institution_id' : { $type : 2 } } ).forEach( 
    function (x) {   
      x.institution_id = parseInt(x.institution_id); // convert field to int
      db.applicants.save(x);
})
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This did it. Didn't realized the column was being recorded as text.